# How to make GUI Emacs use all available space when running maximized on linux?

Tags: linux, gui-emacs

GUI Emacs running maximized on my Linux (centos7+kde) is not using all the available space leaving some space around the borders, specially at the top and the bottom.

Sample of GUI emacs running "maximized" where you can still see the desktop wallpaper (and you should not):

[image: emacs running maximized]

All other apps (kde, gnome, etc) don't have this problem, when you click on maximize button, you cannot see the desktop wallpaper (expected behaviour).

In both cases (emacs and any other app) I use the maximize button provided by the OS. Using `M-x toggle-frame-maximized` as suggested has the same (wrong) effect. Using `M-x toggle-frame-fullscreen` works better in that emacs uses all the screen, but hides the window frame and the OS panel at the bottom, which is not what I want, I just want it to run maximized.

Appreciate if anyone knows how to make GUI Emacs use all the space available when running maximized.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you maximized the Emacs frame.  I suspect you will be looking for `toggle-frame-fullscreen`.

Comment: Thanks for comment @Dan , the question you mention is about full screen, not maximize. Related but not the same. Please consider unmark it as duplicate.

Comment: Found solution here: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/5633  Turns out problem was selected font and the command (setq frame-resize-pixelwise t) solves the issue.

Comment: Go ahead and post your comment as an answer, but please add a little background explanation for others that might come across this post in the future.  Once the system lets you, please go ahead and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found solution on this github: 
[The window frame cannot be maximized 100% to suit the whole screen](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/5633)

Seems like the problem was the selected font and setting the variable "frame-resize-pixelwise" to anything other than nul (default) solves the issue. I have added this line to my .emacs as suggested there:

```
(setq frame-resize-pixelwise t)
```

After restart emacs (just load the config file was not working for me on this one), hitting the maximize button or executing the emacs maximize command "M-x toggle-frame-maximize" works as expected and emacs uses all available space so desktop wallpaper hides completely